# VBA : AppActivate not working on minimize EXE (Kill running process by process ID)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have VBA code to be run as EXE application when a button is clicked in Excel. My code works well, but it doesn't work when it's minimized.
My code is here:

```
Sub GoToMenu()
    Dim prvDir As String

    On Error GoTo CallApp
    'Get current directory before change
    prvDir = CurDir

    'Change to workbook directory
    ChDrive ThisWorkbook.Path
    ChDir (ThisWorkbook.Path)

    'Active program via title
    AppActivate ("My exe file title")

    'Change back to previous directory
    ChDrive prvDir
    ChDir prvDir

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

CallApp:
    'Run MenuExcel.exe
    Shell ThisWorkbook.Path + "\ExcelMenu.exe", vbNormalFocus

    'Change back to previous directory
    ChDrive prvDir
    ChDir prvDir
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can solved my question. I used the concept "Close then Re-open". And my solution like code below.

```
Sub GoToMenu()
    Dim prvDir As String

    On Error GoTo CallApp
    'Get current directory before change
    prvDir = CurDir

    'Find "ExcelMenu" process and kill it before reopen
    Call CloseExcelMenu

    'Change directory to workbook directory
    ChDrive ThisWorkbook.Path
    ChDir (ThisWorkbook.Path)

CallApp:
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Run ExcelMenu.exe
    Shell ThisWorkbook.Path + "\ExcelMenu.exe", vbNormalFocus

    'Change back to previous directory
    ChDrive prvDir
    ChDir prvDir
End Sub
```

I add sub for close my exe before run it again.

```
Sub CloseExcelMenu()
    Dim strComputer As String
    Dim objServices As Object, objProcessSet As Object, Process As Object

    'Find running Process ID "ExcelMenu.exe"
    strComputer = "."

    Set objServices = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" _
        & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2")
    Set objProcessSet = objServices.ExecQuery _
        ("Select Name, ProcessID FROM Win32_Process", , 48)

    'Find the process ID with Process name
    For Each Process In objProcessSet
        If Process.properties_("Name").Value = "ExcelMenu.exe" Then
            'Script for terminate process with image name
            Shell "taskkill /PID " & Process.properties_("ProcessID"), vbNormalFocus
        End If
    Next

    Set objProcessSet = Nothing
End Sub
```

And these are my reference.
Find running process ID:
[VBA Getting program names and task ID of running processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26277214/vba-getting-program-names-and-task-id-of-running-processes)

Kill processes: 
[VBA script to close every instance of Excel except itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526228/vba-script-to-close-every-instance-of-excel-except-itself)