# win32com.client.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application") does not find Excel when opened in a separate instance (excel /x)

Tags: python, excel, win32com

When I open Excel from the cmd line with the "excel" command, then
`win32com.client.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application")`
returns the Excel object I'd expect.

But when I open Excel with a new instance, with "excel /x" from the Command Prompt, then Python doesn't recognize Excel.Application.

My guess is the COM application name is different when opening it this way (e.g. something like Excel.Application2). How can I find out what the COM application name is?

I am calling this Python code from a VBA call to the Shell, so ideally I would like to find the relevant Excel.Application name that called that VBA.

(I've tried digging around the registry and haven't figured it out yet.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reference the COM objects of all the running Excel application instances, including hidden and without workbooks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63562678/how-to-reference-the-com-objects-of-all-the-running-excel-application-instances)